# How to insert repeated message in google protocol buffer _pb2.py file

Tags: python, buffer, protocols

How to insert repeated message in google protocol buffer _pb2.py file

Comment: Could you please be more specific? If you are trying to edit a generated _pb2.py file by hand this is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

make changes to your .proto file. Look at the example : http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/pythontutorial.html